# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority in .net 5

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, .net-5, x509certificate

I am getting this error only with the application developed in .net 5.0,. For .net 4.5* application it is working fine.
With .net 5.0 console application when calling WCF service getting SSl/TLS issue. Already tried below code but not working:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateServerCertficate;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
```

I have written this lines in Main function before creating the host:

```
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
```

Complete error is as below:
**Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority**

Binding Used for WCF call is as below:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding
            {
                CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
                UseDefaultWebProxy = true,
                AllowCookies = false,
                MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom,
                Name = "dlBinding",
                BypassProxyOnLocal = false,

                Security =
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential,
                Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate,
                    ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic,
                }
            }
            };
```

Comment: Verified the certificate, it is valid and good as same certificate is working just fine with .net 4.5 applicaiton

Comment: I'm guessing that the .NET 5 pipeline isn't using ServicePointManager, since that's deprecated.

Comment: @bartonjs So Any other alternative i can use ??

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with WCF to know an answer, sorry. You’d want to find someplace that you can hook up that delegate closer to your request (I.e. maybe there’s something in the Security property/object)